# Query MongoDB with Powershell

Tags: json, mongodb, shell, powershell

I have JSON document in my mongodb looks like following:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "_item": "car",
   "brand": [
        {"name": "BMW", "model": "series 3"},
        {"name": "Audi", "model": "A4"}
   ]
 }
```

I have a snippet of powershell script to query the document above

```
$query = new-object MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument("item", "car")
$result = $mongoCollection.FindOne($query)
```

The $result returns the whole document.

I would like to get a model name only, for a specific brand name. For example, I would like to return "A4" using the key name "Audi". Could you help me how to query this?

Comment: try: $doc = new-object MongoDB.Bson.Document
$doc.Add("brand.Name", 1) $query = new-object MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument("item", "car")
$result = $mongoCollection.FindOne($query, $doc)

Comment: Instead of using `FindOne()`, you can use `Find()` with [`SetFields()`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.2/html/02ce5f11-0d44-cff9-91eb-b188bfd6ea91.htm) to [limit fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) in the results returned from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I am not super familiar with mongoDB but I looking at their documentation (http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/) and as that's json something like this should work. You're basically retrieving the node with the key of name and value of audi, then printing out the result. At least, if it works like I think it does.

```
$query = new-object MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument("name", "Audi")
$result = $mongoCollection.FindOne($query)
foreach($res in $result) {
   write-host $res.model
}
```

Comment: FYI `FindOne()` returns a single result, not an iterator. The original question is actually asking how to do a projection to [return a specific field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).

Comment: @Stennie You are right

Comment: And what is the solution?